# Multiple class query not working

Tags: javascript, class, dojo, selector

I have this HTML-element:

```
<div class="option default"></div>
```

...and I try to get to it in Dojo like this:

```
var el = dojo.query(".option.default");
```

But when I try:

```
alert(dojo.attr(el, "class"));
```

...I get `undefined`.

**Update:**

For some reason, this works:

```
alert(el.attr("class"));
```

How come the other method doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dojo.query() returns a list of DOM nodes based on a CSS selector, not a single element.
You would need to do:

```
var els = dojo.query(".option.default");
var el = els[0];
alert(dojo.attr(el, "class"));
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/L35k6/

Comment: @Orolin Well, jQuery does the same thing as Dojo, but yeah, I hear you.

Comment: @Orolin: take a look at the vast functionality given by `dojo.NodeList` (the type of object returned, *consistently*, by `dojo.query`, regardless of how many items match the query) - http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo/NodeList - always having this functionality available from a call to `dojo.query` tends to outweigh the notion that a single node query result should be a special case.  Easy enough to tack on `[0]` in the cases where you are interested in the node itself.  Consistency and requiring you to type 3 extra characters every now and then isn't much of an argument that a framework "sux".

Answer (score 1):

Would add to the comment but I can't.

@Orolin, how does Dojo know that you know you're expecting a single Node to be returned. If it special cased single elements then anywhere you call dojo.query() and genuinely don't know how many elements you're expecting to get back, you'd have to test yourself. That would be horrid, and take more than three characters!

If you really want this functionality, just do one of the following:

```
dojo.queryFirst = function() {
    return(dojo.query(arguments)[0]);
}
```

or, if you must

```
dojo._oldQuery = dojo.query;
dojo.query = function() {
    var nodes = dojo._oldQuery(arguments);
    return nodes.length > 1 ? nodes : nodes[0];
}
```